# Loan Calculation Wrong

Tags: finance

iam creating some simple loan calculation.

let say iam taking 1000USD with 8% Interest loan for 1 year, and payable for 12 Month.

To get the total interest paid:

```
(1000USD x 8%) + 1000USD = 1080USD (total interest + Principal)
```

For Monthly installment :

```
1080USD / 12 Month = 90USD (Monthly Installment)
```

Monthly Interest is :

```
8%/12 = 0.006667
```

And to get the monthly interest of each month will be:

```
(Current Loan Balance x Monthly Interest)
```

Here is payment schedule for 12 month:

```
Month  |  Installment | Principal  | Interest | 
1      |  90          | 82.80      | 7.20     |
2      |  90          | 83.40      | 6.60     |
3      |  90          | 84.00      | 6.00     |
4      |  90          | 84.60      | 5.40     |
5      |  90          | 85.20      | 4.80     |
6      |  90          | 85.80      | 4.20     |
7      |  90          | 86.40      | 3.60     |
8      |  90          | 87.00      | 3.00     |
9      |  90          | 87.60      | 2.40     |
10     |  90          | 88.20      | 1.80     |
11     |  90          | 88.80      | 1.20     |
12     |  90          | 89.40      | 0.60     |
-------|--------------|------------|----------|
TOTAL  | 1080         | 1033.20 ** | 46.80 ** |
```

The problem is the ** sign on the total. where the

```
Total Principal for 12 Month is 1033.20 
&
Interest is 46.80
```

where it should be

```
Total Principal = 1000
Total Interest = 80
```

anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that the interest at each month is applied to the outstanding loan, which includes previous residule interest.

Even though your calculations show that you pay the full interest each month, it does not show the 'interest on interest'.

Answer (score 0):

Your payment is wrong. The payment is 86.99 dollars.  The below is the amortization schedule that should you get. Please read more about how loan is amortized over one year and learn the formulas for payment, monthly interest and monthly pricipal.  You can use  PMT, IPMT and PPMT formulas in EXCEL to obtain the same and draw out a schedule.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/amortization_schedule.asp

[image]